# Accessing content of the web page after simulating click using ghost.py

Tags: python, screen-scraping, ghost.py

I am simulating click of a button using Ghost.py.But unable to figure out how to get the content which is loaded after clicking the button.

```
from ghost import Ghost

ghost = Ghost(wait_timeout=40)
page, extra_resources = ghost.open("http://www.samsung.com/in/consumer/mobile-phone/mobile-phone/viewall")
#ghost.wait_page_loaded()
n=2;

print type(ghost.click("input#txtViewAll"))
```

What to do next to get the dynamically loaded content?

PS:looked in google.Could not get answer

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be the answer:

```
page, resources = ghost.evaluate(
    "document.getElementById('txtViewAll').click();", expect_loading=True)
```

Regards,